# Return Specific data without writing specific query for that

Tags: firebase, machine-learning, google-cloud-firestore, tensorflow2.0

I am using Firestore & want to get the data of a specific type without writing any special query for that.

For Eg. - Here I have added a query for getting games. And in each game, there is a category which is like - `hockey`, `football` etc.

```js
firestore()
    .collection('Games')
    .get()
    .then(snaps => console.log(snaps.docs))
```

Now there's another table where I can set the game category like `hockey`. Now Without reading the value from this table. I want my `games` collection should return only the games associated with the `hockey` category.

Is there any way I can do it? Whether it's by Machine Learning / Cloud functions or some other way & Algorithm so that Firestore can automatically read values and return that specific data.

Comment: If there is a category field in each game, you can use a query to get the games about hockey: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Basically - I have another scenario. I want to show feeds to users which they are most interested in. If they watch any video more than 50%, I add scores to users for that category and want to show further feeds related to that. I can query for each type of video category they visit. So I am wondering if it can be done in some other way.

Comment: I understand that you want to add preferences to users when they watch a video, then show them videos according to those preferences. If that is correct I think you could do it using [array membership queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership), which can be found in the documentation shared by Frank.

Comment: Not So, This is a basic example which I shared but my use case is much more. So queries on the array are not going to help me.

Comment: Could you please explain me what limitation would that approach have for you? That way I can better understand your situation. Additionally I understand by your last comment that you are expecting a large amount of queries, please edit the question to mention that and any other limitations that should be taken into account.